# Why are ${[0]}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Why are ${[0]}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?

I think there are multiple ways to approach this but I'm not sure. I think somehow we can use the Lagrange theorem ($|G/H||H|=|G|$) to prove this, but I don't know how. Or using the fact that 7 is prime? I feel like that may have something to do with it as well.

Comment: So why not make more of an effort? If there is a subgroup, what is its order?

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$ is has to do with the order being prime. As the order of the subgroup need divide the order of the group.

Comment: Both your guesses are involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have identified, the reason why is a combination of $7$ being prime and the use of Lagrange's Theorem.

Let $H\le G= \Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$. Then $|H|$ divides $|G|=7$ by Lagrange's Theorem. Since $7$ is prime, this means $|H|$ is either $1$ or $7$. But the only subgroup of $G$ of order $1$ must be $\{[0]\}$, since each subgroup of $G$ contains the identity $[0]$. The only subgroup of $G$ of order $7$ must be $G$ itself, since the elements of $G$ are "exhausted" for lack of a better word.

Hence the only subgroups are $\{[0]\}$ and $G$.

There is nothing special here about $7$. Indeed, you can replace it by any prime.